# angular 5 pass parameter

Tags: angular, angular5

I quite new to Angular 5 and AngularFireList I downloaded [this starter template](https://github.com/bave8672/angular-firebase-starter)

They use a state map in the todos folder where they have push the input value to the database. But I want to push data to the database with the value of input with it.

Here they push data:

```
 const ref = this.categoryService.categories().push({
     name: category.name,
     description: category.description,
     uid: '',
  });

 return ref.set({
         name: category.name,
         description: category.description,
         uid: ref.key,
});
```

And here is the `this.categoryService.categories()` method:

```
categories(): AngularFireList<Category> {
    return this.db.list(`/restaurants/${this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}/restaurant_menu/`);
}
```

Than I create a pages folder my self where I load the categories like this:

```
categories$ = this.categoriesService.categories().valueChanges();
```

What I tried is to give the `categroy.name` as paramater to `categories()` like this:

```
const ref = this.categoryService.categories(category.name).push({
    name: category.name,
    description: category.description,
    uid: '',
 });
```

And than set the name to the service:

```
categoryName: any;
categories(category_name): AngularFireList<Category> {
    this.categoryName = category_name

    //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE THE CATEGORY_NAME TO NEST IT IN RESTAURANT_MENU

    return this.db.list(`/restaurants/${this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}/restaurant_menu/${category_name}`);
}
```

Than write a function to retrieve the value in the category service like this:

```
getCategoryName(){
   return this.categoryName;
}
```

And than in the pages folder call the `getCategoryName method`

```
categoryName: any = this.categoriesService.getCategoryName();

categories$ = this.categoriesService.categories(categoryName).valueChanges();
```

But this returns me undefined could someone clear this out or show me how this is done in best practise?

Comment: You need to subscribe to `valueChanges()` to get the values. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505041/1350162

Comment: so what you say is smth like this:


`categoryName: any = this.categoriesService.getCategoryName();`


`categories$ = this.categoriesService.categories(categoryName).valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
         console.log(data);
        })`

Comment: But the categoryName I want to query is undefined...

Comment: Yes, so you seem to be assigning `this.categoryName = category_name` in that `categories` method, but I dont see you calling it anywhere?

Comment: Also, you might have to use a subject (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html) if that value is going to keep changing, and you want to always keep getting the latest value.

Comment: @callback yes I do at the last code block categoryName = this.categoriesService.getCategoryName();


And the value is going to keep changing is there a way to just call them all, to show them all.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but how about `categories()` ? It is the one where you **set** the categoryName. I dont see it being called anywhere?

Comment: In the categories$ var

Comment: Well when you are calling `categoryName: any = this.categoriesService.getCategoryName();` the first time, `this.categoryName` is still undefined!

Comment: @callback so I have to call `categories()` before the `getCategoryName()`?

Comment: @callback could you please help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167676/discussion-between-callback-and-sreinieren).

Comment: @callback are you available now?

Comment: yes I am for a bit!